# Word for "No I in Team"

Tags: hypernyms

I heard a song this morning that had "We put the *us* in *trust*" in its lyrics. It reminded me of the maxim "There is no *I* in *team*." I've heard other, gloomier examples like "harm in harmony" and "utility in futility." Is there a hypernym for "insight based on the presence (or absence) of substrings in another string"?

Comment: How "insightful" would such ***puns*** have to be to merit this hypothetical hypernym? Would the greengrocer's joke: [There's no effing tomatoes!](http://www.reddit.com/r/Jokes/comments/1940do/luigis_fruit_shop/) count?

Comment: I am on a quest to answer this question.

Comment: "You can't have slaughter without laughter!"

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I prefer the football supporters' "There's only one *f* in Fulham".

Comment: The 'p' is silent, as in pswimming!

Comment: Would you--could you--expand/expatiate on the "substrings in another string"? I'm at a loss . . ..

Comment: @WS2 Please note there is [no "p" in our ool](http://imgc.allpostersimages.com/images/P-473-488-90/71/7159/CVQM100Z/posters/welcome-to-our-ool-no-p-sign-art-print-indoor-outdoor-rigid-resin-sign.jpg).

Comment: Don't forget to keep the Fun in Fundamental!

Comment: There's no I in team – but there's a ME!

Comment: @FumbleFingers "Insightful" was meant to separate meaningful (a better word; I may edit to that) statements such as "*Earth* without *art* is *eh*" or (since I think Will's comment is quoting Simpsons too) ["You can't spell *obsequious* without *iou*"](http://imgur.com/HLHeG) from meaningless ones like "You can't spell *cowbell* without *w*." That said, *f in tomatoes* is insightful.

Comment: @rhetorician My vague language aims at generality. Though most of the above examples involve words nested in words, I would like the hypernym to be broad enough to own "You can't spell union without u-n-i" (where u-n-i is said as "You and I"), which conveys a sensical idea not through a word but through the pronunciation of a substring. My current definition of substring is "an ordered string of consecutive letters found in another string." Ideally a substring can span words like "*injustice* is found in *certain justice*". But I'm happy if I find a term for meaningful words in other words.

Comment: No problem! I want to amend one thing I said though: I now think it's better to include space as a letter in the ideal substring's definition. It's not a good example, but one might look like "Who likes Shar Pe*i do*gs?" with the answer "i do" contained in the phrase. (Improper capitalization/spelling is overlooked in the ideal example that allows for Ned Flanders' "Putting the S-T-U (stew) back in student.")

Comment: A closely-related feature of cryptic crosswords is usually called a ***hidden*** (sometimes ***embedded***) answer. For example, the clue for 25ac in [yesterday's Guardian](http://www.theguardian.com/crosswords/cryptic/26144) was *Never, ever, ever restricting worship* (answer ***revere** = 'worship'*, the letters of which occur consecutively in the "instruction" part of the clue).

Comment: @Mike  I believe the conclusion of that corollary is: *... it's in the "A" hole*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a word is within a word, it is called a **kangaroo word**. Also known as: *marsupial*, or *swallow word*

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kangaroo_word) says:

> A kangaroo word is a word that contains letters of another word, in
>   order, with the same meaning. For example: the word ***masculine*** contains
>   the word ***male***, which is a synonym of the first word; similarly, the
>   word ***observe*** contains its synonym ***see***.
>   The etymology of the phrase *kangaroo word* is from the fact that kangaroos carry their young (known as joeys) in a body pouch. Likewise, *kangaroo words* carry their *joey words* within themselves. **Twin kangaroos** are *kangaroo words* containing two joey words (for example: **container** features both *tin* and *can*). In contrast, an **anti-kangaroo word** is a word that contains its antonym; for example: **covert** carries *overt*, **animosity** carries *amity*

In Richard Lederer's, *The Word Circus*: *A Letter-Perfect Book*. 1997:

> "Among the kangaroo words that yield the most *joviality* and *joy* are
>   those that conceal multiple joeys. Let's now *perambulate*, ***ramble***, and
>   ***amble*** through an exhibit of this species. Open up a *container* and you
>   get a ***can*** and a ***tin***. When you have *feasted*, you ***ate*** and have ***fed***. When
>   you *deteriorate*, you **rot** and **die**. A *routine* is both ***rote*** and a ***rut***.
>   Brooding inside *loneliness* are both **loss** and **oneness**.
>
> "A *chariot* is a ***car*** and a ***cart***. A charitable *foundation* is both a ***fund***
>   and a ***font***. Within the boundaries of a *municipality* reside **city** and
>   ***unity***, while a *community* includes ***county*** and ***city***."

Thus ***harm*** in *harmony* could be said to be an *anti-joey word* and ***futility*** an *anti-kangaroo word* because it carries the word *utility*.

Answer (score 2):

I also agree that there probably is no word to describe this.

How about calling it a "**substring saying**"?

Ex: You know that *substring saying* that goes, "There's no 'I' in team."? Well, have you heard, there is a me in team?

Comment: +1: This works for many cases. There is one case that's given me trouble. The saying "No x in Nixon" is a palindrome that comments on a substring. But it says its substring *x* is not part of *Nixon*, when it is. This can be defended until it is insightful (suppose Nixon would not say 'no' to some party; he did not 'x out' the options they provided) but standing alone it is contradictory and not insightful (by my narrow definition of it). I think I need a stronger word than *saying*, something that implies there can be no contradiction.

Comment: Good point. I like it! Perhaps adding a "true|false" prefix would make sense. Ex: a "true substring saying" is "There's no 'I' in team."

Comment: I like it. I was hoping for a pre-established, in-the-dictionary term but "true substring saying" meets all my other criteria. I've posted a bounty. If no other answers, this one's yours. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would like to propose another option for the construction of the *phrase*.  Kangaroo words certainly describe the unpacking portion of the construct, but I'd still hope we could come up with something to encompass the algorithmic usage described in the original question.  Though I think *substring saying* is on the right path, I think besides my programmer and math buddies, it might not get much love.

Even after trying to stretch the definition of synecdoche, clitics, and tmesis (and then checking back in here and seeing the beauty of *kangaroo word*), I still wanted to stretch the inner-wordplay to an encompassing phrase.  After trying out some other math terms with more generic application, I wrote down **"Interset Reflection"**.  Though *interset* has some maths usage, it also has a generic definition of "set among", and *reflection* speaks to the action needed to see the phrase meaning (you must look back and see that T-E-A-M does NOT have an I in it...) and the fact that thinking on the construction reveals the creative semanticism.

Thank you Dan for posting this and giving us all the chance to flex our linguistic muscles!  Also, thanks to all the contributors for furthering this exercise!

Comment: *Interset Reflection* is good, but I really like that you brought [*tmesis*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmesis) to my attention. Thanks, Mike!

Answer (score 1):

First, the insight you refer to is contrived. It is not a deliberate formation of words with the intent of providing multiple viewpoints and food for thought. It is more a creative exercise and probably has its origins in the advertising world. Therefore, it is unlikely that there is a hypernym to describe the phrases in your query. We may just have to coin a word or phrase to refer to such pithy capsules of wisdom. How about " creative semanticism".

Comment: I think it's very likely you're right that there's no word to describe what I'm looking for. But what I'm looking for must describe puns like these only. These do fall under "creative semanticism" but I think [Swifties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Swifty), for example, do also.