# Term for "[Idiom], [Rhyme]" like "See you later, alligator."

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idioms, terminology, rhymes

Browsing the web, I came across this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDQEz.png) of the cast of the television show *Community* using a type of structure familiar to me, and I wondered if there's a name for it.

The most familiar instance is likely "See you later, alligator." And because it brings to memory the similar "In a while, crocodile," 
I found a phrase that loosely encapsulated these with the Wikipage for [Parting Phrases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parting_phrase).

Then I remembered other examples from the musical number [*Telephone Hour*](http://www.stlyrics.com/lyrics/byebyebirdie/thetelephonehour.htm) in the 1963 film Bye Bye Birdie, in which teenyboppers *greet* each other on the phone with phrases like

```
What's the story, morning glory?
What's [the] tale, nightingale?
...
What's the word, humming bird?
```

And I've found [several](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090216225838AAMaZEE) [pages](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=340671) of lesser-known but valid examples of what I wish to describe, some examples being "So long, King [Donkey?] Kong" and "Mañana, iguana." So I was tempted to label this question "Term for '[*Salutation*], [*Rhyming Organism*]'."

Now I wanted the term also to include the quotes from *Community,* most of which (an example being "You're on your own, Al Capone") are preceded by a phrase that is not a salutation. But growing up we had a book called ["See You Later, Alligator"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0440848695); it contained the *alligator* and *crocodile* phrases, but it also had ones that were something like "See you on the veranda, panda" and "See you in pajamas, llamas." Because these opening phrases are not idioms or figures-of-speech, my ideal term does **not** include them.

And even *organism* may not quite capture the terminal phrase, as shown in Jeebs' example using a title in 2002's [Men in Black II](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120912/quotes?item=qt0431203): "Let's make it happen, cap'n." So I have generalized it to *rhyme*.

The *idiom* restriction aside, I suspect there may be a term like [*iambic pentameter*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iambic_pentameter) or *Oom-Pah-Pah* to describe the rhythm these phrases make when spoken. I am open to suggestions like these but my preference lies with terms more like [antimetabole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antimetabole), a word I recently learned from ELU which focuses more on the structure or composition of the phrase than on its sound.

Is there a word or phrase that precisely describes expressions of the form "[Idiom], [Rhyming Phrase]"?

Comment: Perhaps since 'See you later, alligator' is the lead example perhaps - a haleybill?

Comment: @MarkRaishbrook: The parts in my post asking only for a word were mistakes. All along, what I've really been meaning to find is a description more concise (maybe even more technical) than "sayings like *See you later, alligator*". (I've edited the question to reflect this.) I am kind of "grasping at straws" with questions like these, but in the past I've gotten [answers](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/144020/word-for-no-i-in-team) that "filled the bill" quite nicely.

Comment: Something that all the phrases have in common is that they are addressed at someone specific.  The rhyme tag is being used in place of the person's actual name or a more standard way of addressing them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe there isn't a well-established term for these phrases but there is a general term used that is based on the term *catchphrase*:

- **rhyming catchphrase** / catch-phrase

I've found the relevant excerpt below and there are usages in [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22rhyming+catchphrase%22&rlz=1C1VDKB_enCA994CA994&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiYx9DKnpT5AhWjX_EDHfS_DGoQ_AUoAXoECAEQCw&biw=1536&bih=746&dpr=1.25) as well.

> If you’re a native English speaker you’ve probably heard a few popular rhyming catch-phrases like, ‘see you later, alligator‘ or ‘after a while crocodile‘. - *[happyhoursspanish.com](https://www.happyhourspanish.com/okey-dokey-rhyming-catch-phrases-in-spanish/)*

Also, we can call the latter part of the phrase a **rhyme-tag**:

> a word or phrase used primarily to produce a rhyme. - *[britannica.com](https://www.britannica.com/art/rhyme-tag)*

---

Furthermore, the book *[Slang: The People's Poetry](https://books.google.es/books/about/Slang.html?id=3xkLAQAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y#:%7E:text=Slang%2C%20writes%20Michael%20Adams%2C%20is,on%20the%20cusp%20of%20art.)* (by Michael Adams) describes these phrases in a variety of ways, as in rhyming {something}. Additionally, it talks about the differences between [rhyming slang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhyming_slang) and these phrases.

Moreover, the author thinks that they are a verse and poetic; and describes them as *rhyming couplets*.

> Of course, there are lots of rhyming salutations, farewells, and queries; some of them are generic and familiar, slang clichés. The most famous of these is *See you later, alligator*; the usual response is the equally all-purpose *In a while, crocodile*.

> Along with all of these slangy things, rhymes like *What's your story, morning glory?* or *How's it goin', protozoan*? are poetry, or at least verse; they are, in some elements, poetic. Each of these rhymes is really a couplet or pair of couplets (or, I suppose, one could interpret each as an internally rhymed single line of verse): 
> How's it goin', 
> Protozoan? 
> See you later, 
>  Alligator. 
>  Not too soon, 
> You big baboon.
> Granted, if these are miniature poems, they aren't very sophisticated, not villanelles or complexly idiosyncratic free verse poems.

Comment: I like the syllabic generality of *couplet*. (A person could have a long idiom followed by its rhyme, as in my weird example of "I'll see you in heaven, 007.") In fact, I think the term I'm looking for would only require one thing more: that one half be auxiliary to the other. In the above examples, the second part is filler, while the first is usually somehow informational. This would allow some cases I ideally don't want (like the veranda/panda case) but it should also describe the above examples.

Comment: And it's good research. I can say "rhyming couplets *like 'See you later, alligator'*" and people will know exactly what I mean. But the term *rhyming couplet* itself is broad, covering such examples like [*True wit is nature to advantage dress'd;
What oft was thought, but ne'er so well express'd.* -- Alexander Pope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Couplet). I'll post bounty on this tomorrow, but I think what you've found could very well be the best we'll find.

Answer (score 1):

From Wikipedia, an [internal rhyme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_rhyme) or middle rhyme is a rhyme that occurs within a single line of a verse.

Although the article in Wikipedia is not brilliant, I think the connection with hip hop and swing era lyrics is important and missing in your question

I've found other links that give examples closer to the ones you've listed:

- [britannica](http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/290573/internal-rhyme)
- [yourdictionary.com](http://examples.yourdictionary.com/examples/examples-of-internal-rhyme.html)

Comment: I like the Britannica reference. I'm not very familiar with hip-hop/swing, but I was thinking of mentioning "My, my, Miss American Pie." The part from the Wiki that I think may cause confusion is that an *internal rhyme* can also be used to mean "compound rhyme," or "rhyme-within-a-rhyme"; the phrases I'm thinking of can be pithy and simple. But from the definitions, especially those last two, I think it can be used to describe "[Idiom], [Rhyme]": +1.

Answer (score 0):

Many of these trite cute sayings are *cliché*.  They would also qualify as *jingles*. But neither of these terms are specific.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following neologisms:

**humonymy** *(humorous partial homonymy) or* **echonymy** *(the last meaningful word being meaninglessly echoed) or* **a humorhyme** *(a humorous, nonsensical, rhyming couplet)*

The phenomenon reminds me of *Cockney rhyming slang*, but Cockney for people who are not in the know, who are not insiders, the rhyming word being kept rather than dropped. "See you later, alligator!" is a partial "cockney-fication".

An example of Cockney speech given on Wikipedia is:

Go up the *stairs*. > Go up the *apples and pears*. (*stairs* replaced with a rhyming word or phrase) > Go up the *apples*. (the part of the word or phrase containing the rhyme is dropped)

Similarly, then, "See you later, alligator!" if it were properly "cockney-fied" should become:

See you later. > See you alligator. > See you alli.

Cockney worked for a small, tightly-knit community of quick-witted people with similar backgrounds.

"See you later, alligator!" works for… America!

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there's an exact phrase for this, but a '**rhyming valediction'** might be a good way to describe it. Ermanen's answer is an excellent one, but 'rhyming catch-phrase' doesn't quite capture the fact that it's a parting term: 'See you later, alligator' might work better described as a 'rhyming valediction'.

Comment: The actual question makes it clear that this is broader than valedictions.