# Name of a word where you can continually remove one letter from the beginning or end

Tags: is-it-a-word, word-formation

*This is possibly off-topic here - please redirect me if necessary*

I am looking for the name of a type of word where you can continually remove one letter from the start or end of the word, until there is just one letter left, and every intermediate word is a valid word in the English language.

For example, `brandy` is such a word, because after each letter is removed below, we get another word:

```
brandy
brand
bran
 ran
  an
  a
```

What is the name for words with this property?

*I'm new on ELU.SE; I can probably do with some help with tagging this question correctly.*

Comment: I don't know if such words have a name, but another example is _startling_: starting-staring-string-sting-sing-sin-in-I.

Comment: You do not remove from only the start or end there, @Shoe

Comment: Similar to *trim* in programming , left-trim, right-trim, except that *trim* removes leading/ trailing blank spaces. You could try asking on a programming Q&A where string handling is an interesting topic. Or [linguistics.se] where they must have already research deep into these things.

Comment: I think it's a *joey*, in any case strongly related check out these questions [Word for “No I in Team”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/144020/word-for-no-i-in-team/145739#145739) and [Is there a term for a word inside another word?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105107/is-there-a-term-for-a-word-inside-another-word)

Comment: @Mari-LouA *joey* is a good suggestion, though is slightly more general that what I am looking for.  In fact according to some sources in the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kangaroo_word), if any of the consecutive letters in the joey are also consecutive in the kangaroo, then it is disqualified.  I like the suggestion though, so +1 to you if you add it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of an aphetic word game:

> **Aphetic** *(adj)* shortened by dropping a letter or a syllable from the beginning of a word; as, an aphetic word or form

From [definitions.net](http://www.definitions.net/definition/aphetic).

Comment: I don't think so [1880, from aphesis](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/aphetic), coined by OED editor Sir James A.H. Murray (1837-1915) for "gradual and unintentional loss of a short unaccented vowel at the beginning of a word" (as squire from esquire), from Gk. aphienai "to let go, to send forth," from apo- "from" + hienai "to send." and from [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Aphetic) *The loss of an initial, usually unstressed vowel, as in cute from acute.* The OP is asking about **continually** omitting letters from a word whereby a new word is created every time.

Comment: A *repetaphetic*? But that doesn't help with the loss of the final letters.