# Is there a term for a word made of some of the letters taken (in any order) from another word?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology

I'm looking for a  word to describe something.

Say I have the word "note". Then "Eton" would be called an **anagram** of "note".
What would you call "not" or "ton" in relation to note – possibly a "partial anagram"?

Comment: On similar lines: [Is there a term for a word inside another word?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105107/is-there-a-term-for-a-word-inside-another-word/105124#105124) But Joey words are not supposed to be anagrams

Comment: But in my answer of mine, "kangaroo words" allowed anagrams [Word for “No I in Team”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/144020/word-for-no-i-in-team)

Comment: I recommend an essay by James Thurber to you:  'Do You Want to Make Something Out of It? (Or, if you put an "o" on "understo," you'll ruin my "thunderstorm")').

Comment: I thought it was indeed called a "partial anagram". I am happy to have learned about Joey words serendipitously